# Counting specific character from file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Could someone explain to me what this part: `~/[bcdfg]/)` of the following code:

```
awk ' {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~/[bcdfg]/) count++;
```

means? I know that it counts how often b,c,d,f appear but I don't understand how it's working. What does "~" exactly do and also I don't understand how this part  `[bcdfg]/)` works.

Comment: Use the [GNU awk user guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html). The tilde is a regular expression match, and the text between slashes is a regular expression. By the way, this code counts the number of **fields*g that contain one of these letters; it does not count the number of **letters**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is the "regular expression matching" operator. It takes the string on the left-hand side and compares it to the regular expression pattern on the right hand side. See [Regexp Usage](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Usage.html)

`/.../` specifies a regular expression literal -- see [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html)

`[bcdfg]` is a regular expression bracket expression: it matches against a single character, one of `b`, `c`, `d`, `f`, `g` -- see [Using Bracket Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html)

This pattern is not *anchored*, so it is testing if `$i` **contains** one of the specified letters.

Comment: @berndbausch I didn't see you comment (somehow) before I wrote my answer. Sorry for stealing your thunder.